# Is there a tag in XHTML that you can put anywhere in the body - even inside TABLE elements?

Tags: html, xhtml, diff, tags, metadata

I would like to be able to place an empty tag anywhere in my document as a marker that can be addressed by jQuery. However, it is important that the XHTML still validates.

To give you a bit of background as to what I'm doing: I've compared the current and previous versions of a particular document and I'm placing markers in the html where the differences are. I'm then intending to use jQuery to highlight the parent block-level elements when `highlightchanges=true` is in the URL's query string.

At the moment I'm using `<span>` tags but it occurred to me that this sort of thing wouldn't validate:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Old row</td>
    </tr>
    <span class="diff"></span><tr>
        <td>Just added</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So is there a tag I can use anywhere? Meta tag maybe?

Thanks for your help!

Iain

*Edit: On the advice of codeka, I may look for a better difference engine and I may have found one that is attuned to finding differences in XHTML: http://www.rohland.co.za/index.php/2009/10/31/csharp-html-diff-algorithm/*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTML comments and [this plugin](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1563-jQuery-Comments-Plug-in-To-Access-HTML-Comments-For-DOM-Templating.htm) (or [this one](http://www.lukedyson.co.uk/blog/5/grab-html-comments-using-jquery/)).

Comment: Nice! I'll definately have a look at this and get back to you!

Comment: This is probably a better idea, though it would still be a problem if your difference engine works on a character-by-character basis, with no knowledge of HTML (for example, what would happen if someone adds a new attribute to a tag?)

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just modify the class of elements that have changed?

```
<p class="diff other-class">Something changed</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Old row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="diff">
        <td>Just added</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I guess I could, but the Diff engine I'm using is not language-aware. It only compares strings by a given single-character delimiter. I suppose I could parse my xhtml and add a class if the inner text contains the control character... I have no idea where to start with that though! :)